# Why does browser change automatically format date?

Tags: javascript, browser

In my Java webApp a REST service return a json that has a java.sql.Date field with format **"YYYY-MM-DD"** (example **"2013-12-24"**). When I build the response, inside the objecto o I have the following data:

```
Response response = Response.ok().entity(o).build();
```

[image]
When I get this field from REST response, it is formatted in this way **"Month dd, YYYY"** (example **'December 24, 2013'**). Why does the browser change the format?[image]

Moreover the format in the browser is different between me and my colleague:

1. my colleague: 'December 24, 2013'
2. me: 'Dicembre 24, 2013' (Italian format)

Why?

When I use this stringDate in the function **new Date(stringDate)** in my case I get *"Invalid Date"*.
Is there a way to uniform all StringDate in english or italian format for all users so I can use the method new Date()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the application formatting the date to the user's locale?

Comment: By the way, `java.sql.Date` is obsolete, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. You should be using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead.

Comment: I suggest you provide a sample of the actual REST response. If XML or JSON, the browser should not be altering the content.

Comment: Is this question about Java or Javascript?

Comment: Javascript...Why the browser changes the format in javascript json and why i have italian format and my clleague english format....